# Editing a Row Value in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this

```
Pick   Name     Team Round           Player Position Position..
1    1   Javi   Texans     1 Patrick Mahomes        QB        QB1
2    2 Justin   Chiefs     1  Russell Wilson        QB        QB2
3    3  Blake   Titans     1   Lamar Jackson        QB        QB3
4    4 Connor Dolphins     1   Deshaun Watson       QB        QB4
5    5  Isaac  Jaguars     1     Carson Wentz       QB        QB5
6    6   Fitz     Rams     1     Dak Prescott       QB        QB6
```

with more rows of course and some of the rows in the Player, Position and Position... Column are empty because they haven't been drafted yet. Is there a way to just manually insert the names, pos, pos... of the newly drafted players.

I tried

```
Redraft[112, "Player"] <- "Calvin Ridley"; Redraft
```

Since the empty cells start on row 112, but it just came up as N/A

When I do that I also get an error message:

```
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "Calvin Ridley") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

and the data frame looks like

```
08  108    Jack    Packers     4   TE3       Darren Waller       TE
109  109  Justin     Saints     4   LT6        Taylor Lewan       LT
110  110     Sam   Steelers     4   FS5         Kevin Byard       FS
111  111  Jeremy    Falcons     4   LB7      Isaiah Simmons       LB
112  112    Will      Bills     4     1                <NA>         
113  113  Jeremy      Colts     4     1
```

And heres the whole data frame:

```
structure(list(Pick = 1:384, Name = structure(c(12L, 14L, 1L, 
2L, 7L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 9L, 12L, 9L, 2L, 10L, 16L, 11L, 13L, 20L, 
13L, 17L, 14L, 8L, 3L, 3L, 19L, 5L, 19L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 18L, 
15L, 15L, 18L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 19L, 5L, 19L, 3L, 3L, 8L, 14L, 
17L, 13L, 20L, 13L, 11L, 16L, 10L, 2L, 9L, 12L, 9L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 
7L, 2L, 1L, 14L, 12L, 12L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 9L, 12L, 
9L, 2L, 10L, 16L, 11L, 13L, 20L, 13L, 17L, 14L, 8L, 3L, 3L, 19L, 
5L, 19L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 18L, 15L, 15L, 18L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 
19L, 5L, 19L, 3L, 3L, 8L, 14L, 17L, 13L, 20L, 13L, 11L, 16L, 
10L, 2L, 9L, 12L, 9L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 14L, 12L, 12L, 
14L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 9L, 12L, 9L, 2L, 10L, 16L, 11L, 
13L, 20L, 13L, 17L, 14L, 8L, 3L, 3L, 19L, 5L, 19L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 
4L, 18L, 15L, 15L, 18L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 19L, 5L, 19L, 3L, 3L, 
8L, 14L, 17L, 13L, 20L, 13L, 11L, 16L, 10L, 2L, 9L, 12L, 9L, 
6L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 14L, 12L, 12L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 8L, 
6L, 9L, 12L, 9L, 2L, 10L, 16L, 11L, 13L, 20L, 13L, 17L, 14L, 
8L, 3L, 3L, 19L, 5L, 19L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 18L, 15L, 15L, 18L, 
4L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 19L, 5L, 19L, 3L, 3L, 8L, 14L, 17L, 13L, 20L, 
13L, 11L, 16L, 10L, 2L, 9L, 12L, 9L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 
14L, 12L, 12L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 9L, 12L, 9L, 2L, 
10L, 16L, 11L, 13L, 20L, 13L, 17L, 14L, 8L, 3L, 3L, 19L, 5L, 
19L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 18L, 15L, 15L, 18L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 19L, 
5L, 19L, 3L, 3L, 8L, 14L, 17L, 13L, 20L, 13L, 11L, 16L, 10L, 
2L, 9L, 12L, 9L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 14L, 12L, 12L, 14L, 
1L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 9L, 12L, 9L, 2L, 10L, 16L, 11L, 13L, 
20L, 13L, 17L, 14L, 8L, 3L, 3L, 19L, 5L, 19L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 
18L, 15L, 15L, 18L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 19L, 5L, 19L, 3L, 3L, 8L, 
14L, 17L, 13L, 20L, 13L, 11L, 16L, 10L, 2L, 9L, 12L, 9L, 6L, 
8L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 14L, 12L), .Label = c("Blake", "Connor", 
"Dakota", "FFB", "Fitz", "Haydon", "Isaac", "Jack", "Jackson", 
"Jacob", "Jacob H", "Javi", "Jeremy", "Justin", "Nick", "Pete", 
"Sam", "Simon", "Tucker", "Will"), class = "factor"), Team = structure(c(30L, 
10L, 31L, 13L, 17L, 24L, 18L, 6L, 3L, 8L, 7L, 28L, 9L, 21L, 14L, 
11L, 4L, 15L, 29L, 27L, 20L, 1L, 25L, 5L, 23L, 26L, 32L, 19L, 
12L, 16L, 22L, 2L, 2L, 22L, 16L, 12L, 19L, 32L, 26L, 23L, 5L, 
25L, 1L, 20L, 27L, 29L, 15L, 4L, 11L, 14L, 21L, 9L, 28L, 7L, 
8L, 3L, 6L, 18L, 24L, 17L, 13L, 31L, 10L, 30L, 30L, 10L, 31L, 
13L, 17L, 24L, 18L, 6L, 3L, 8L, 7L, 28L, 9L, 21L, 14L, 11L, 4L, 
15L, 29L, 27L, 20L, 1L, 25L, 5L, 23L, 26L, 32L, 19L, 12L, 16L, 
22L, 2L, 2L, 22L, 16L, 12L, 19L, 32L, 26L, 23L, 5L, 25L, 1L, 
20L, 27L, 29L, 15L, 4L, 11L, 14L, 21L, 9L, 28L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 6L, 
18L, 24L, 17L, 13L, 31L, 10L, 30L, 30L, 10L, 31L, 13L, 17L, 24L, 
18L, 6L, 3L, 8L, 7L, 28L, 9L, 21L, 14L, 11L, 4L, 15L, 29L, 27L, 
20L, 1L, 25L, 5L, 23L, 26L, 32L, 19L, 12L, 16L, 22L, 2L, 2L, 
22L, 16L, 12L, 19L, 32L, 26L, 23L, 5L, 25L, 1L, 20L, 27L, 29L, 
15L, 4L, 11L, 14L, 21L, 9L, 28L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 6L, 18L, 24L, 17L, 
13L, 31L, 10L, 30L, 30L, 10L, 31L, 13L, 17L, 24L, 18L, 6L, 3L, 
8L, 7L, 28L, 9L, 21L, 14L, 11L, 4L, 15L, 29L, 27L, 20L, 1L, 25L, 
5L, 23L, 26L, 32L, 19L, 12L, 16L, 22L, 2L, 2L, 22L, 16L, 12L, 
19L, 32L, 26L, 23L, 5L, 25L, 1L, 20L, 27L, 29L, 15L, 4L, 11L, 
14L, 21L, 9L, 28L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 6L, 18L, 24L, 17L, 13L, 31L, 10L, 
30L, 30L, 10L, 31L, 13L, 17L, 24L, 18L, 6L, 3L, 8L, 7L, 28L, 
9L, 21L, 14L, 11L, 4L, 15L, 29L, 27L, 20L, 1L, 25L, 5L, 23L, 
26L, 32L, 19L, 12L, 16L, 22L, 2L, 2L, 22L, 16L, 12L, 19L, 32L, 
26L, 23L, 5L, 25L, 1L, 20L, 27L, 29L, 15L, 4L, 11L, 14L, 21L, 
9L, 28L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 6L, 18L, 24L, 17L, 13L, 31L, 10L, 30L, 30L, 
10L, 31L, 13L, 17L, 24L, 18L, 6L, 3L, 8L, 7L, 28L, 9L, 21L, 14L, 
11L, 4L, 15L, 29L, 27L, 20L, 1L, 25L, 5L, 23L, 26L, 32L, 19L, 
12L, 16L, 22L, 2L, 2L, 22L, 16L, 12L, 19L, 32L, 26L, 23L, 5L, 
25L, 1L, 20L, 27L, 29L, 15L, 4L, 11L, 14L, 21L, 9L, 28L, 7L, 
8L, 3L, 6L, 18L, 24L, 17L, 13L, 31L, 10L, 30L), .Label = c("49ers", 
"Bears", "Bengals", "Bills", "Broncos", "Browns", "Buccaneers", 
"Cardinals", "Chargers", "Chiefs", "Colts", "Cowboys", "Dolphins", 
"Eagles", "Falcons", "Giants", "Jaguars", "Jets", "Lions", "Packers", 
"Panthers", "Patriots", "Raiders", "Rams", "Ravens", "Redskins", 
"Saints", "Seahawks", "Steelers", "Texans", "Titans", "Vikings"
), class = "factor"), Round = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L), 
    Pos.. = structure(c(49L, 60L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 
    27L, 76L, 43L, 50L, 51L, 92L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 77L, 56L, 
    57L, 58L, 89L, 59L, 85L, 61L, 103L, 3L, 106L, 35L, 62L, 36L, 
    63L, 42L, 10L, 107L, 18L, 64L, 108L, 65L, 109L, 19L, 11L, 
    110L, 86L, 37L, 111L, 12L, 20L, 112L, 66L, 21L, 38L, 13L, 
    90L, 78L, 81L, 30L, 14L, 15L, 82L, 39L, 16L, 17L, 93L, 94L, 
    4L, 22L, 95L, 96L, 2L, 97L, 67L, 5L, 68L, 87L, 83L, 84L, 
    6L, 31L, 44L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 7L, 28L, 101L, 32L, 29L, 8L, 
    33L, 88L, 69L, 79L, 102L, 9L, 104L, 40L, 23L, 24L, 105L, 
    25L, 45L, 80L, 46L, 26L, 47L, 91L, 48L, 34L, 41L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L), .Label = c("1", "C1", "CB1", "CB10", "CB11", "CB12", 
    "CB13", "CB14", "CB15", "CB2", "CB3", "CB4", "CB5", "CB6", 
    "CB7", "CB8", "CB9", "DE1", "DE2", "DE3", "DE4", "DE5", "DE6", 
    "DE7", "DE8", "DE9", "DT1", "DT2", "DT3", "FS1", "FS2", "FS3", 
    "FS4", "FS5", "LB1", "LB2", "LB3", "LB4", "LB5", "LB6", "LB7", 
    "LG1", "LT1", "LT2", "LT3", "LT4", "LT5", "LT6", "QB1", "QB10", 
    "QB11", "QB12", "QB13", "QB14", "QB15", "QB16", "QB17", "QB18", 
    "QB19", "QB2", "QB20", "QB21", "QB22", "QB23", "QB24", "QB25", 
    "QB26", "QB27", "QB28", "QB3", "QB4", "QB5", "QB6", "QB7", 
    "QB8", "QB9", "RB1", "RB2", "RB3", "RB4", "RG1", "RT1", "RT2", 
    "RT3", "SS1", "SS2", "SS3", "SS4", "TE1", "TE2", "TE3", "WR1", 
    "WR10", "WR11", "WR12", "WR13", "WR14", "WR15", "WR16", "WR17", 
    "WR18", "WR19", "WR2", "WR20", "WR21", "WR3", "WR4", "WR5", 
    "WR6", "WR7", "WR8", "WR9"), class = "factor"), Player = structure(c(87L, 
    91L, 72L, 38L, 14L, 24L, 79L, 78L, 3L, 57L, 90L, 70L, 107L, 
    31L, 39L, 10L, 56L, 68L, 20L, 4L, 94L, 93L, 45L, 52L, 51L, 
    44L, 80L, 97L, 62L, 67L, 40L, 98L, 101L, 89L, 50L, 9L, 85L, 
    104L, 19L, 41L, 109L, 58L, 106L, 81L, 37L, 26L, 29L, 27L, 
    18L, 86L, 60L, 84L, 17L, 74L, 105L, 95L, 111L, 63L, 76L, 
    55L, 92L, 110L, 12L, 15L, 64L, 96L, 34L, 25L, 61L, 103L, 
    54L, 21L, 53L, 49L, 59L, 108L, 71L, 83L, 77L, 82L, 102L, 
    7L, 65L, 2L, 69L, 32L, 22L, 75L, 43L, 5L, 8L, 46L, 35L, 42L, 
    23L, 88L, 6L, 11L, 60L, 48L, 16L, 13L, 30L, 36L, 73L, 33L, 
    99L, 28L, 100L, 66L, 47L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "A.J. Brown", 
    "Aaron Donald", "Aaron Rodgers", "Adoree' Jackson", "Allen Robinson", 
    "Amari Cooper", "Anthony Harris", "Antonio Brown", "Baker Mayfield", 
    "Bobby Wagner", "Byron Jones ", "Cameron Jordan", "Carson Wentz", 
    "Casey Hayward", "CeDee Lamb", "Chandler Jones", "Chase Young", 
    "Chris Godwin", "Christian McCaffrey", "Cooper Kupp", "Courtland Sutton", 
    "D.J. Moore", "Dak Prescott", "Danielle Hunter", "Darius Leonard", 
    "Darius Slay", "Darren Waller", "DaVante Adams", "David Bakhtiari", 
    "DeAndre Hopkins", "Deforest Buckner", "Demarcus Lawrence", 
    "Denzel Ward", "Derek Carr", "Derrick Henry", "Derwin James", 
    "Deshaun Watson", "Drew Brees", "Drew Lock", "Dwayne Haskins", 
    "Ezekiel Elliott", "Fletcher Cox", "Gardner Minshew", "George Kittle", 
    "Harrison Smith", "Isaiah Simmons", "J.J. Watt", "Jaire Alexander", 
    "Jalen Ramsey", "Jamal Adams", "Jared Goff", "Jarrett Stidham", 
    "Jason Kelce", "Jeffrey Okudah", "Jimmy Garappolo", "Joe Burrow", 
    "Joey Bosa", "Jordan Love", "Josh Allen", "Juju Smith-Schuster", 
    "Julio Jones", "Justin Simmons", "Keenan Allen", "Kenny Golladay", 
    "Kevin Byard", "Khalil Mack", "Kirk Cousins", "Kyle Fuller", 
    "Kyler Murray ", "La'el Collins", "Lamar Jackson ", "Laremy Tunsil", 
    "Marcus Peters", "Marcus Williams", "Marlon Humphrey", "Marshon Lattimore", 
    "Matt Ryan", "Matthew Stafford", "Michael Thomas", "Mike Evans", 
    "Minkah Fitzpatrick", "Mitchell Schwartz ", "Myles Garrett", 
    "Nick Bosa", "Odell Beckham Jr.", "Patrick Mahomes ", "Patrick Peterson", 
    "Quenton Nelson", "Ronnie Stanley", "Russell Wilson ", "Ryan Ramczyk", 
    "Ryan Tannehill", "Sam Darnold", "Saquon Barkley", "Stefon Diggs", 
    "Stephon Gilmore", "T.J. Watt", "Taylor Decker", "Taylor Lewan", 
    "Teddy Bridgewater", "Terron Armstead", "Terry McLaurin", 
    "Tom Brady", "Travis Kelce", "Tre White", "Tua Tagovailoa", 
    "Tyrann Mathieu", "Tyreek Hill", "Von Miller", "Zack Martin"
    ), class = "factor"), Position = structure(c(10L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 5L, 10L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 16L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 15L, 10L, 14L, 10L, 16L, 
    3L, 16L, 7L, 10L, 7L, 10L, 8L, 3L, 16L, 4L, 10L, 16L, 10L, 
    16L, 4L, 3L, 16L, 14L, 7L, 16L, 3L, 4L, 16L, 10L, 4L, 7L, 
    3L, 15L, 11L, 12L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 13L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 16L, 16L, 
    3L, 4L, 16L, 16L, 2L, 16L, 10L, 3L, 10L, 14L, 13L, 13L, 3L, 
    6L, 9L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 3L, 5L, 16L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 14L, 
    10L, 11L, 16L, 3L, 16L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 16L, 4L, 9L, 11L, 9L, 
    4L, 9L, 15L, 9L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "C", 
    "CB", "DE", "DT", "FS", "LB", "LG", "LT", "QB", "RB", "RG", 
    "RT", "SS", "TE", "WR"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
384L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you show the result with NA you got. It works for me : "112   <NA>     <NA>   NA    <NA> Calvin Ridley     <NA>       <NA>""

Comment: I updated the post with the error message and the new data frame

Comment: also, the column Position... does the same thing, but it works for Position.

Comment: Hi, please share data using `dput`. Help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610

Comment: done, didnt even know that was a thing lol

Comment: @JacksonDels See, this is important. Otherwise we can't see the structure of your data. This revealed that you're dealing with a factor column, see my answer.

Comment: Thanks for telling me! I'm new to coding and Stack Overflow so any new info is awesome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're dealing with a factor column. `"Calvin Ridley"` isn't yet a level of the factor. After adding it you can rename the cell.

```
class(Redraft$Player)
# [1] "factor"

levels(Redraft$Player) <- c(levels(Redraft$Player), "Calvin Ridley")
Redraft[112, "Player"] <- "Calvin Ridley"
Redraft[112, "Player"]
# [1] Calvin Ridley
# 112 Levels:  A.J. Brown Aaron Donald Aaron Rodgers Adoree' Jackson Allen Robinson ... Calvin Ridley
```

Answer (score 1):

jay.sf's answer is correct, of course, but I'd add my 2¢ since I think it's missing the point.

The reason you have factors instead of plain strings here in the first place, is kind of a historical accident with R being a statistical language. In practice, you rarely want to be dealing with factors in a dataframe of this kind. You probably want your player names to be plain-old strings.

Typically when you read a dataframe from a file, e.g. via `read.csv`, you have the option to pass the argument `stringsAsFactors = TRUE`, to ensure that strings are kept as strings rather than converted to factors. Some people (e.g. [this guy](https://www.r-bloggers.com/fun-with-rprofile-and-customizing-r-startup/)) feel so strongly against this bizzare default behaviour, that they include a line in their .Rprofile to make importing data with `stringsAsFactors=T` as their default. (but this is dangerous for writing code that works the same across users with different .Rprofile initializations!)

If you already have the dataset, you can convert your factors to strings instead:

```
df[ , 'Player'] <- as.character( df[ , 'Player' ] )
```

You can now continue with your analysis without worrying about factors and their annoyances.

E.g. setting a new name is as simple as you'd expect:

```
df[112,'Player'] <- 'Calvin Ridley'
```